# .NET MVC routing - catchall at start of route?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is there any way I can match:

```
/a/myApp/Feature

/a/b/c/myApp/Feature

/x/y/z/myApp/Feature
```

with a route that doesn't specifically know what the path before myApp/Feature is?

What I essentially want to do is:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
  "myAppFeatureRoute", "{*path}/myApp/Feature",
  new { controller = "myApp", action = "Feature" });
```

but you can't put a catchall at the start of a route.

If I just try "{path}/myApp/Feature", that will match "/a/myApp/Feature" but not "/a/b/c/myApp/Feature".

I tried a regex catchall as well, that did nothing to help.

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
  "myAppFeatureRoute", "{path}/myApp/Feature",
  new { controller = "myApp", action = "Feature", path = @".+" });
```

The reason I'm doing this is that I am building a feature that is used in a CMS, and can sit anywhere in the site structure - I can only be certain about the end of the path, not the beginning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a constraint for that,

```
public class AppFeatureUrlConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (values[parameterName] != null)
        {
            var url = values[parameterName].ToString();
            return url.Length == 13 && url.EndsWith("myApp/Feature", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ||
                    url.Length > 13 && url.EndsWith("/myApp/Feature", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

using it as,

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "myAppFeatureRoute",
    url: "{*url}",
    defaults: new { controller = "myApp", action = "Feature" },
    constraints: new { url = new AppFeatureUrlConstraint() }
    );

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

then the following urls should be intercepted by `Feature` action

```
/a/myApp/Feature

/a/b/c/myApp/Feature

/x/y/z/myApp/Feature
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know you could do this. Works well!