# Error requesting access token for client default after upgrading to Duende Identity Server

Tags: identityserver4, duende-identity-server

After upgrading from IdentityServer4 (v2) to Duende Identity Server, I am getting this error when an app is trying to get a token to connect to an API:

`error requesting access token for client default`

There is no "Error" in the logs, but the token request returns a 404:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher:
    |No candidates found for the request path '//connect/token'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware:
    |Request did not match any endpoints
Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.EndpointRouter:
    |No endpoint entry found for request path: //connect/token
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics:
    |Request finished HTTP/1.1 POST https://accounttest.veic.org//connect/token 
    application/x-www-form-urlencoded 29 - 404 - - 2.0641ms
```

This same app used to work fine before the Identity Server upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, this error has nothing to do with Duende Identity Server.  The problem is that upgrading .NET to use [EndPoint Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#routing-startup-code) can cause this issue.

The previous code to `app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute` was more gracious about accepting double slashes in a URL.  The new `app.UseEndpoints` routing does not handle this double slash in the URL and route it to an action.

Here is a good answer about how to [deal with the double slash in the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59304132/1804678).